# How to trim multiline string to n lines max

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a very long input string that's multiline, in a local variable $INPUT, for example:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

How do I trim it to n lines max, let's say n=3, and add a message at the end:

```
a
b
c
... message too long
```

This is what I have, don't work on multi-line:

```
$OUTPUT=$('$INPUT' | awk '{print substr($0, 1, 15) "...")
```

Comment: `OUTPUT=$(head -n 3 <<<"$INPUT"; echo "text")`?

Comment: Regarding `I have a very long input string that's multiline, in a local variable` - that's usually a red flag that there's something wrong with your approach earlier in your code as it's very rare for carrying around shell variables populated with long, multi-line strings to be the right approach to anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
output=$(echo "$input" | awk -v n=3 'NR>n {print "... message too long"; exit} 1')
```

or

```
output=$(echo "$input" | sed -e '3{a\... message too long' -e 'q}')
```

```
output=$(echo "$input" | sed -e '3{$!N;s/\n.*/\n... message too long/' -e 'q}')
```

POSIXly

```
output=$(echo "$input" | sed -e '3{
  $!N
  s/\n.*/\n... message too long/
  q
  }')
```

or with GNU sed:

```
output=$(echo "$input" | sed -e '4{i\... message too long' -e 'Q}')
```

Comment: I went with your sed solution but they are all good.

Comment: @BillSoftwareEngineer actually the sed one is wrong - it will class a message that is exactly 3 lines as "too long"

Comment: OK thank you for the update, I will modify my code as such

Comment: Why do you need to escape the first `.`? Is that a typo? It doesn't seem to make any difference on my system where `seq 5 | sed -e '4{i... message too long' -e 'Q}'` works exactly like `seq 5 | sed -e '4{i\... message too long' -e 'Q}'`.

Comment: @terdon tbh I always confuse myself with that one... iirc `itext` is a GNU extension but then `i\text` (without a newline between the `i\ ` and the `text`) probably requires GNU sed anyhow, so you're correct it might just as well be `i...`

Answer (score 4):

```
OUTPUT=$(echo "$INPUT" | perl -pe '1..3 or exit')
```

Comment: How do I add a message at the end?

Comment: Maybe `OUTPUT=$(echo "$INPUT" | perl -ple '1..3 or do {print "message too long"; exit}')`? But I'm sure Ole can come up with a better one.

Answer (score 2):

I propose this:

```bsh
# convert the variable into an array
$ mapfile -t arr < <(echo "$INPUT")
# use printf and slice the array into the fisrt three elements
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]:0:3}" "... message too long"
a
b
c
... message too long
```

Comment: That would print "message too long" even if it wasn't, e.g. if INPUT was 1 or 2 lines instead of more than 3.